# Create PHP array from MySQL column, using auto_increment column as index

Tags: php, mysql

Much like [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538229?sort=votes#sort-top), I wish to store a MySQL column in a php array (as opposed to storing by row). However, I want the array indexes to match those of the database's primary key.

For instance, for the following database:

> id         name
>    1          Joe
>    2          Mary
>    9          Tony
>
> $name['9'] == "Tony"

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query($q);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $array[$row["id"]] = $row["name"];
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to initialize the array before the while loop with $array = array(); or it will throw a notice on the first row. Also, please don't name your variable "$array".

Comment: Pretend it's called $foo then.

Comment: I'm naming $jordan for sure :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

yes,

```
$names = array();
foreach ($rows as $r) {
   $names[$r['id']] = $r['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper library can make this easier, e.g. with [ADODb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/):

```
$array = $db->GetAssoc("select id,name from mytable");
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I have my row results as arrays, I use this method:

```
function convertArrayToMap(&$list, $attribute, $use_reference=FALSE) {
    $result = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
        if ($use_reference) $result[$list[$i][$attribute]] = &$list[$i];
        else $result[$list[$i][$attribute]] = $list[$i];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And the method call:

```
$mapOfData = convertArrayToMap($mysql_results, 'ID');
```