# Php array from mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I looked at this question:
[Create PHP array from MySQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538229/create-php-array-from-mysql-column)
and what seems to work for everyone is this:

```
$array= array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM inloggen"))) {
    $array[] = $row['Username'];
    }
```

But when I run this code it infinitely adds the first username in my database to the array.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-executing the query endlessly, because you're doing it as part of your while, so if any records are returned , your code will re-query and return the same result time and again

Execute the query, then iterate over the result set

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM inloggen");
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[] = $row['Username'];
}
```

Caveat: The MySQL extension is a deprecated interface; you should be using MySQLi or PDO