# Using MySQLI to fetch a column and convert to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

So I've been trying various other threads, but none seem to use MySQLI, nor work.
I'm attempting to query a MySQL table via MySQLI, the convert the returned column into an array to be used later. Here's what I have so far.

```
$sql = new mysqli("URL", "user", "pass","db") or die ("Not connected");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}
$sql_query = "SELECT Desired_column FROM Table_Name";
$result_array = $sql->query($sql_query);
while($row = $result_array->fetch_row()) {
    $rows[]=$row;
}
$result_array->close();
$sql->close();
return $rows;
```

And yes... I'm a complete novice at coding so PHP vets, enjoy seeing how far you've come!

The error I am getting is

> Call to a member function fetch_row() on Boolean on line 60

Comment: What is `$result`?

Comment: ^ In case its not clear. Why is `$result` not `$result_array`?

Comment: You MUST BE GETTING AN ERROR in your error log. Look for it, read it and then fix the code

Comment: Call to a member function fetch_row() on Boolean on line 60

Comment: change `$result_array` to `$result`

Comment: I've already defined $result earlier, so for the sake of clarity, all instances of $result have been changed to $result_array

Comment: Okay well you code a moment ago showed something different and we can only troubleshoot what we have.

Comment: Which line is line 60 out of the 13 lines you have shown us

Comment: Ended up solving it. Thank you all so much for the help!

Comment: If you're a complete novice, I suggest starting off with PDO instead of mysqli. Based on this code though, you may want to start with fundamentals instead of jumping in to database code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Desired_column FROM Table_Name";
$results = mysqli_query($sql, $query);

$rows = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

## Edit 1

- Changed `array_push($rows, $row);` to `$rows[] = $row;` to reduce function calls

Comment: fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232766/difference-between-array-push-and-array. Using `$rows[] = $row` over `array_push()` is preferable. Likewise `mysqli_fetch_all()` would probably be the most straightforward when nothing fancy is done in the loop.

Comment: That seems to have worked! thank you!

Comment: @nerdlyist cheers, i'll update my answer accordingly :)

Comment: @Spholt also try and describe what you changed. People coming in may not see it.

Comment: I already have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1538229/2943403