# Splitting array elements php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Example

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "select name from documentation");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
print_r($row); echo "<br />";
}   

Array ( [name] => Orders ) 
Array ( [name] => Documents ) 
Array ( [name] => Letters )
```

Question. How can I split array elements?
 So for example $row[0] would be Orders; $row[1] => Documents; etc... 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For indexed array generation, use `$output[] = $row['name'];`.  This is an under-researched question.

Comment: It's not a question in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create PHP array from MySQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538229/create-php-array-from-mysql-column)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an array and add items to it in each iteration.

```
$myArray = [];

$query = mysqli_query($db, "select name from documentation");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    //Print what you need to print
    $myArray[]=$row['name'];
}
```